# Is there a reason on not allowing lambdas to deduce the return type if it contains more than one statement?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, return-type

Taken from the C++0x FDIS (n3290):

> If a lambda-expression does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as if the lambda-declarator were (). If a lambda-expression does not include a trailing-return-type, it is as if the trailing-return-type denotes the following type:
>
> - if the compound-statement is of the form
>     { attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> return expression ; }
>     the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion
>     (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> - otherwise, void.

Why doesn't the standard allow the compiler to analyse the compound-statement and determine the return type based on the first found `return` statement?

I can't see any reason to not allow this, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Example:

```
int main(){
  // compiler: nope.jpg
  auto l = []{
    // one computation
    // another computation
    // yet another one!
    return something;
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Please no "because the standard says so" answers. :)

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly: "...determine the return type based on the first found return statement?", are you asking why compilers are not allowed to handle lambdas with multiple `return` statements?

Comment: @In silico: No, rather why it's not allowed to just omit the trailing-return-type for more complicated lambdas. Also, multiple return statements are allowed afaik, just not with different (and non-covariant or implicitly convertible) types.

Comment: Because C++ is already painfully difficult to implement, likely.

Comment: This is core issue 975 in the committee documents. It says there shouldn't be such restriction. I don't know what its final status is.

Comment: @n.m.: Oh, nice to know the committee is aware of this! Actually, the same should apply for functions in general, imho. :/

Comment: @Xeo functions in general are a different beast at all. Because you need take into account that there may be a forward declaration (is it an error?), recursive calls other stuff. There was already discussion about it, but IIRC it's a difficult issue compared to the lambda thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no technical reason for this. IIRC it was already implemented by the GCC C++ maintainer and he said it's trivial to implement.

The committee is very conservative about accepting features into the Standard so they went with this simple form of deduction and will later hopefully accept a more powerful form. See the reason for rejection on [US 30](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#US30) comment.

[DR 975](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#975) is already marked "ready" so chances are good it will be accepted.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for the answer! I'll leave this question open for another few days, but I guess there'll be no other (better) answers to come (except maybe from Howard Hinnant who could complement your answer with insider info). :)

Comment: Note that there's now [an official proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html) for this extended return type deduction for all function types, and not only lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

`Why doesn't the standard allow the compiler to analyse the compound-statement and determine the return type based on the first found return statement?`

In my opinion, reasons are **inheritance**, **implicit typecast** to `void*` and `0` typecasted to `int`, which makes it difficult for compiler implementers to deduce type from the first `return` statement.
See the below examples:

```
// "B" is a derived by "D"
int main(){
  auto l = []{
    return (D*)(...);  // should it be "D*" (derived)
    // computation
    return (B*)(...);  // no it should be "B*" (base)
  }
}
```

Second,

```
int main(){
  auto l = []{
    return (int*)(...);  // should it be "int*"
    // computation
    return (void*)(...);  // no it has to be "void*"
  }
}
```

Third one,

```
int main(){
  auto l = []{
    return 0;  // should it be "int"
    // computation
    return (double)(...); // no it has to be "double"
  }
}
```

Also there is one more reason related to giving a **compilation error** message, when two unrelated `return` are found:

```
int main(){
  auto l = []{
    return TYPE1;
    // computation
    return TYPE2;
  }
}
```

Now, question would arise that what useful compiler message should be printed to user ? The error message has to be only for one of the `return` statements. Which `return` to choose ?

Comment: Covariance is already checked by compilers on, e.g., virtual functions, so that shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: @Xeo, I have added few more use cases to my answer. Those are just on logic that what could be motivation.

Comment: On which return to choose: The first one. If not, the user has to make this clear with a trailing return type.

Comment: @Xeo, correct it should choose "The first one". But as you see in the earlier cases I mentioned, the compiler is not choosing the 1st ones as the 2nd ones are better match. In short, everything will have an answer but at the cost of compilation time. Assume a case where you have several `return` types of related types. Now compiler has to deduce by seeing them all, it will add complexity. I am not against this concept, but rather I am presenting some possible reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not a restriction but an *allowance* to leave out `-> decltype(expression)` when the body is just `return expression`. It is pretty obvious what the return type is in that case.

Your suggestion requires a lot more work for the compilers and a lot more rules for us, the programmers. Does it buy us much?

Comment: I know I had a very specific reason in mind when asking this question, an example where the automatic type deduction would be really helpful, but for the sake of my life, I can't remember it. :(

Comment: After over a year, I remembered: Returning nested lambdas with setup-code before that like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12639578/500104)! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of this kind of code :

```
void foo( bool k )
{
    auto call= [](){ if( k ) return 42; else return 'c'; };  // what is the return type?
    call();
}
```

Here the return type could be int or char. As each one of those types is implicitely convertible to the other, that's too ambiguous for the compiler to guess what is the return type. So to avoid confusion or to avoid the compiler implementation to decide witch type it should be, the comitee simply tell that this should produce an error( a diagnostic) allowing the programmer to specify wich type was required.

So it's just to make sure compilers will not compile code that is too ambiguous to allow return type guessing.