# When is the move constructor called in the `std::move()` function?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

The function `std::move()` is defined as

```
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T && t)
{ 
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>( t ); 
}
```

There are four places where I can imagine the move constructor to be called:

1. When the parameter is passed.
2. When the cast is performed.
3. When the result is returned.
4. Not in the `std::move()` function itself but possibly at the place where the returned reference ultimately arrives.

I would bet for number 4, but I'm not 100% sure, so please explain your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no move construction going on. `std::move()` accepts a reference and returns a reference. `std::move()` is basically just a cast.

Your guess 4. is the right one (assuming that you are actually calling a move constructor in the end).

Comment: `std::move` is such a silly name because _it doesn't move anything_ (i.e. because, yes, the answer is `4`). I've had this argument with committee members and they are of the opinion that it's fine because "people will only ever use `std::move` as a precursor to moving something". I feel that this completely violates the _spirit_ of C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I find the name `move` confusing too.

Comment: It should have been called `to_movable` or `make_movable`. I guess that is a little too much typing for people using IDE's without auto-completion.

Comment: @usr [Why is `std::move` named `std::move`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21358432/341970)

Comment: @Ali interesting history lesson. Still, `make_movable` is consistent with the main point of that post (and not plain wrong like `move` is. It is undeniably wrong. It does not describe what the method does. It describes something it *doesn't* do.).

Comment: @usr Yes, I agree. I just wanted to let you know that there is an explanation from someone on the C++ standardization committee.

Answer (score 4):

std::move is just a type cast, it tells the compiler that the type is an rvalue.

Comment: That's kinda what I though. Hence `std::move()` actually doesn't move and doesn't even need to lead to a move operation.

Comment: That's why I don't understand some people saying that the move can prevent the (N)RVO. From my experiments with GCC the (N)RVO works just fine with move.

Comment: Using `return std::move(local_var);` instead of just `return local_var;` will indeed inhibit (N)RVO, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12288328/500104).

Comment: @Xeo, I saw this answer but I think it's logic is wrong. Move can convert NRVO into RVO, it doesn't inhibit the optimization per se. Do you have an example when move inhibits RVO, so that I can test it?

Comment: It does inhibit (N)RVO, simply because the standard says (N)RVO is **only** allowed to happen when you write `return local_var;`.

Comment: @Xeo, aren't you confusing NRVO and RVO? You don't need a name for the RVO, and NRVO is an extension of RVO. You can't perform NRVO on rvalue, but you can still perform the optimization (the RVO).

Comment: @ArtemGr if you can observe the difference, `return std::move(local_var);` cannot optimize the move away. If the difference is not observable, the question is, as always, made moot by the as-if rule.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, there is no difference with GCC.

Comment: Try with a move constructor that causes observable effects, like `std::cout << "Hey, I'm moving"`.

Comment: @ArtemGr Try with a more conformant version http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d4bb782e20433f48f9a61cc2106d502d