# Why is std::move named std::move?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, language-design, rvalue-reference, c++-faq

The `std::move(x)` function doesn't really move anything at all.
It is just a cast to an rvalue.
Why was this done?
Isn't this misleading?

Comment: To make matters worse, the three-argument `std::move` actually moves..

Comment: And don't forget about the C++98/03/11 `std::char_traits::move` :-)

Comment: My other favorite is `std::remove()` which doesn't remove the elements: You still have to call `erase()` to actually remove those elements from the container. So `move` doesn't move, `remove` doesn't remove. I would have picked the name `mark_movable()` for `move`.

Comment: @Ali I would find `mark_movable()` confusing also. It suggests there is a lasting side effect where in fact there is none.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

It is correct that `std::move(x)` is just a cast to rvalue - more specifically to an [*xvalue*, as opposed to a *prvalue*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601748/576911).  And it is also true that having a cast named `move` sometimes confuses people.  However the intent of this naming is not to confuse, but rather to make your code more readable.

The history of `move` dates back to [the original move proposal in 2002](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm).  This paper first introduces the rvalue reference, and then shows how to write a more efficient `std::swap`:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(static_cast<T&&>(a));
    a = static_cast<T&&>(b);
    b = static_cast<T&&>(tmp);
}
```

One has to recall that at this point in history, the only thing that "`&&`" could possibly mean was *logical and*.  No one was familiar with rvalue references, nor of the implications of casting an lvalue to an rvalue (while not making a copy as `static_cast<T>(t)` would do).  So readers of this code would naturally think:

> I know how `swap` is supposed to work (copy to temporary and then exchange the values), but what is the purpose of those ugly casts?!

Note also that `swap` is really just a stand-in for all kinds of permutation-modifying algorithms.  This discussion is *much*, much bigger than `swap`.

Then the proposal introduces *syntax sugar* which replaces the `static_cast<T&&>` with something more readable that conveys not the precise *what*, but rather the *why*:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(move(a));
    a = move(b);
    b = move(tmp);
}
```

I.e. `move` is just syntax sugar for `static_cast<T&&>`, and now the code is quite suggestive as to why those casts are there:  to enable move semantics!

One must understand that in the context of history, few people at this point really understood the intimate connection between rvalues and move semantics (though the paper tries to explain that as well):

> Move semantics will automatically come into play when given rvalue
>   arguments. This is perfectly safe because moving resources from an
>   rvalue can not be noticed by the rest of the program (*nobody else has
>   a reference to the rvalue in order to detect a difference*).

If at the time `swap` was instead presented like this:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(cast_to_rvalue(a));
    a = cast_to_rvalue(b);
    b = cast_to_rvalue(tmp);
}
```

Then people would have looked at that and said:

> But why are you casting to rvalue?

---

**The main point:**

As it was, using `move`, no one ever asked:

> But why are you moving?

---

As the years went on and the proposal was refined, the notions of lvalue and rvalue were refined into the *value categories* we have today:

[image: Taxonomy]

(image shamelessly stolen from [dirkgently](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66692/dirkgently))

And so today, if we wanted `swap` to precisely say *what* it is doing, instead of *why*, it should look more like:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(set_value_category_to_xvalue(a));
    a = set_value_category_to_xvalue(b);
    b = set_value_category_to_xvalue(tmp);
}
```

And the question everyone should be asking themselves is if the above code is more or less readable than:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(move(a));
    a = move(b);
    b = move(tmp);
}
```

Or even the original:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(static_cast<T&&>(a));
    a = static_cast<T&&>(b);
    b = static_cast<T&&>(tmp);
}
```

In any event, the journeyman C++ programmer should know that under the hood of `move`, nothing more is going on than a cast.  And the beginner C++ programmer, at least with `move`, will be informed that the intent is to *move* from the rhs, as opposed to *copy* from the rhs, even if they don't understand exactly *how* that is accomplished.

Additionally, if a programmer desires this functionality under another name, `std::move` possesses no monopoly on this functionality, and there is no non-portable language magic involved in its implementation.  For example if one wanted to code `set_value_category_to_xvalue`, and use that instead, it is trivial to do so:

```
template <class T>
inline
constexpr
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
set_value_category_to_xvalue(T&& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);
}
```

In C++14 it gets even more concise:

```
template <class T>
inline
constexpr
auto&&
set_value_category_to_xvalue(T&& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t);
}
```

So if you are so inclined, decorate your `static_cast<T&&>` however you think best, and perhaps you will end up developing a new best practice (C++ is constantly evolving).

**So what does `move` do in terms of generated object code?**

Consider this `test`:

```
void
test(int& i, int& j)
{
    i = j;
}
```

Compiled with `clang++ -std=c++14  test.cpp -O3 -S`, this produces this object code:

```
__Z4testRiS_:                           ## @_Z4testRiS_
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    (%rsi), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%rdi)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Now if the test is changed to:

```
void
test(int& i, int& j)
{
    i = std::move(j);
}
```

There is *absolutely no change at all* in the object code.  One can generalize this result to:  For *trivially movable* objects, `std::move` has no impact.

Now lets look at this example:

```
struct X
{
    X& operator=(const X&);
};

void
test(X& i, X& j)
{
    i = j;
}
```

This generates:

```
__Z4testR1XS0_:                         ## @_Z4testR1XS0_
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    popq    %rbp
    jmp __ZN1XaSERKS_           ## TAILCALL
    .cfi_endproc
```

If you run `__ZN1XaSERKS_` through `c++filt` it produces:  `X::operator=(X const&)`.  No surprise here.  Now if the test is changed to:

```
void
test(X& i, X& j)
{
    i = std::move(j);
}
```

Then there is still *no change whatsoever* in the generated object code.  `std::move` has done nothing but cast `j` to an rvalue, and then that rvalue `X` binds to the copy assignment operator of `X`.

Now lets add a move assignment operator to `X`:

```
struct X
{
    X& operator=(const X&);
    X& operator=(X&&);
};
```

Now the object code *does* change:

```
__Z4testR1XS0_:                         ## @_Z4testR1XS0_
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    popq    %rbp
    jmp __ZN1XaSEOS_            ## TAILCALL
    .cfi_endproc
```

Running `__ZN1XaSEOS_` through `c++filt` reveals that `X::operator=(X&&)` is being called instead of `X::operator=(X const&)`.

And *that's* all there is to `std::move`!  It completely disappears at run time.  Its only impact is at compile-time where it *might* alter what overload gets called.

Comment: While it's nice that we can give it another name, the rest of the world won't recognize it. :/

Comment: Here's a dot source for that graph: I recreated it `digraph D { glvalue -> { lvalue; xvalue } rvalue -> { xvalue; prvalue } expression -> { glvalue; rvalue } }` for the public good :) Download it **[here as SVG](http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/value-categories.svg)**

Comment: Is this still open to bikeshedding? I'd suggest `allow_move` ;)

Comment: `set_value_category_to_xvalue` is far easier to write than that.  `template<class T> constexpr auto set_value_category_to_xvalue(T&& t) noexcept -> decltype(std::move(t)) { return std::move( t ); }` ;)

Comment: @Yakk `noexcept(noexcept(std::move(t)))` to avoid reinventing the wheel. :)

Comment: Just for the history section: In [Mojo](http://www.drdobbs.com/move-constructors/184403855) it was called `as_temporary`.

Comment: @dyp My favorite is still `movable`.

Comment: Scott Meyers suggested renaming `std::move` to `rvalue_cast`: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BezbcQIuCsY&feature=player_detailpage#t=335

Comment: Since rvalue now refers to both prvalues and xvalues, `rvalue_cast` is ambiguous in its meaning:  what kind of rvalue does it return?  `xvalue_cast` would be a consistent name here.  Unfortunately, most people, at this time, would also not understand what it is doing.  In a few more years, my statement will hopefully become false.

Comment: and here is the google charts url for that DOT diagram: [click](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=gv&chl=digraph%20D%20{%20glvalue%20-%3E%20{%20lvalue;%20xvalue%20}%20rvalue%20-%3E%20{%20xvalue;%20prvalue%20}%20expression%20-%3E%20{%20glvalue;%20rvalue%20}%20})

Comment: I haven't really grokked all of this...what is the compiled machine code doing differently when you do `a = static_cast<T&&>(b)` rather than `a = b`?  Is it somehow swapping what the references themselves point to instead of invoking `operator =`, or what?

Comment: `std::enable_move` would have been a better name, or `std::try_move`, or `std::make_moveable`?

Comment: @Nawaz:  So write it for yourself.  Just follow the recipe I've given for `set_value_category_to_xvalue`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: No, I'm used to `std::move` by now. I was thinking loud (like other guys here), even though I knew it cannot be renamed.

Comment: @Andy:  After *only* 2 years, I've updated the answer to address your question. ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant oh, okay, so basically since it produces the type `X&&`, if there is an overload for the function being called (`operator =` in this case, but I assume it could be any function) that takes type `X&&`, it calls that overload instead of one that takes `X&`, and if there is no overload that takes `X&`, the `X&&` gets implicitly cast back to `X&` and that overload is called.  Right?

Comment: @Andy:  Pretty close.  An rvalue `X` can't bind to `X&` (except on VS), but can bind to a `const X&`, and will do so exactly as you describe.

Comment: @HowardHinnant oh, right, that makes sense.  Thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 21):

Let me just leave here a quote from the [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval) written by B. Stroustrup, which is a direct answer to OP's question:

> move(x) means "you can treat x as an rvalue". Maybe it would have
>   been better if move() had been called rval(), but by now move() has
>   been used for years.

By the way, I really enjoyed the FAQ - it's worth reading.

Comment: To plagiarize @HowardHinnant's comment from another answer: Stroustrup answer is inaccurate, as there are now two kinds of rvalues - prvalues and xvalues, and std::move is really an xvalue cast.