# Understanding std::move and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, move, smart-pointers

I am new to c++11 and trying to understand to meaning of `std::move` and `unique_ptr` and wrote the following code, which I use `std::move` on a `unique_ptr` in two different ways:

```
void unique_ptr_plain_move() {
  unique_ptr<int> intptr(new int(10));
  unique_ptr<int> intptr2;

  printf("*intptr = %d\n", *intptr);
  intptr2 = std::move(intptr);
  printf("*intptr2 = %d\n", *intptr2);
  // as expected, crash here as we have already moved intptr's ownership.
  printf("*intptr = %d\n", *intptr);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

void function_call_move(unique_ptr<int>&& intptr) {
  printf("[func] *intptr = %d\n", *intptr);
}

void unique_ptr_function_call_move() {
  unique_ptr<int> intptr(new int(10));

  printf("*intptr = %d\n", *intptr);
  function_call_move(std::move(intptr));
  // this does not crash, intptr still has the ownership of its pointed instance ....
  printf("*intptr = %d\n", *intptr);
}
```

In `unique_ptr_plain_move()`, `intptr2` takes the ownership of `intptr` after `std::move` and therefore we can no longer use `intptr`.  However, in `unique_ptr_function_call_move()`, when using `std::move` in a function call, `intptr` still have its ownership of its pointed instance.  Can I know what exactly happened when we pass a `std::move(unique_ptr)` to a function?  Thank you.

Comment: A call to `std::move` doesn't by itself move anything. It just allows other functions that want to steal contents of the object to do so. `function_call_move` is not such a function.

Comment: std::move creates a RValue Reference from unique_ptr. function_call_move takes a RValue Reference, but until a RValue Reference assignment operator or constructor is used to steal the unique_ptr's information it doesn't get harmed.  Essentially just because you *can* mug it and steal it's info doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: @Dan: thank you very much for your comment.  So it is the `=` operation does the ownership transfer, not the `std::move`, am I right at this part?

Comment: See [Why is `std::move` named `std::move`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key concept here is that `std::move` by itself won't do any moving.
You can think of it as marking the object as a object that can be moved from.

The signature for `function_call_move` is

```
void function_call_move( unique_ptr<int>&& ptr );
```

Which means it can only receive objects that could be moved from, formally known as rvalues, and bind that to a reference. The act of associating an rvalue to a rvalue reference don't invalidate the state of the original object either.

So, unless `function_call_move` actually moves `ptr` to another `std::unique_ptr`inside it, your call to `function_call_move(std::move(intptr));` won't invalidate `intptr` and your usage will be perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't provide the signature for `function_call_move` at the very beginning, but I have provided right after I observed that.  Thank you very much for your detailed answer!