# Why doesn't std::move() of unique_ptr from list<unique_ptr> really move it?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, rvalue-reference

```
using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<int>;

Ptr f(bool arg) {
  std::list<Ptr> list;
  Ptr ptr(new int(1));
  list.push_back(std::move(ptr));

  if (arg) {
    Ptr&& obj1 = std::move(list.front());
    // Here |obj1| and |list.front()| still point to the same location!
    list.pop_front();
    return std::move(obj1);
  }
  else {
    Ptr obj2 = std::move(list.front());
    list.pop_front();
    return obj2;
  }
};

Ptr&& ptr1 = f(true);   // |ptr1| is empty.
Ptr&& ptr2 = f(false);  // |ptr2| is fine.
```

The full source is [here](http://ideone.com/AEP92v).

I don't understand — why do `obj1` and `list.front()` still point to the same location after `std::move()` is called?

Comment: Why do you use so many rvalue-references? If you use `Ptr obj1 =` instead of `Ptr&& obj1 =`, everything should be fine.

Comment: @nosid I have a fuzzy explanation. I'm trying to use the `std::experimental::optional` from libc++ - instead of `Ptr`. My `optional` contains pairs of `unique_ptr`s and move-only objects (i.e. without default ctor). The variant `Ptr obj2 =` doesn't even compile - but the `Ptr&& obj1 =` does. And then I was surprised about the situation that I explained in the question. Of course, I should examine the problem with `optional` itself, but it's easier to make clear the easiest things first.

Comment: Think about the expression `std::move(list.front())` in isolation. If `std::move` did actually move its argument (hint: it does not), where exactly would the object be moved *to*?

Comment: @FredOverflow My guess - it should be moved to the temporary object, like `Ptr()`, that gets destroyed when leaves the scope - in normal situation. But because of rvalue-reference - it should leave a little bit longer.

Comment: Actually, your guess doesn't sound unreasonable, but that's just not how it works.

Comment: std::move doesn't move; it's misnamed, as acknowledged by Stroustrup.  Details and references here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove (and maybe this could be considered a dup of that question).

Answer (score 4):

You have a **reference** to the `std::unique_ptr` inside `list`.

```
Ptr&& obj1 = std::move(list.front());
// ^^ THIS
```

And so when you do

```
list.pop_front();
```

The unique pointer that's in `list` gets destroyed, and you are left with a dangling reference to some object that is already destroyed, which is **illegally** used by returning it from the function.

**UPDATE:** `std::move` there doesn't actually move the `std::unique_ptr`. If we see [how `std::move` is defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), we see that it only returns an r-value reference of the expression being moved. It becomes interesting when you test for it:

```
Ptr&& obj1 = std::move(list.front());
assert(obj1.get() == list.front().get());
```

Your `else` clause does seems fine though, and you should use that pattern for the rest of your code.

```
Ptr obj2 = std::move(list.front());
list.pop_front();  // OK; destroys the moved-from unique_ptr
return obj2;       // OK; obj2 points to something valid and is not a dangling reference
```

[@nosid has summed-up what I want this answer to mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112298/why-does-the-moving-of-stdunique-ptr-from-stdlist-makes-the-copy-instead-in/22112326#comment33544501_22112298).

Comment: `std::move` does not move, it flags something as movable in the current expression.

Answer (score 1):

Without move-semantics `std::unique_ptr` is less useful. With move-semantics **it allows transfer of ownership to another object**.

With `list.push_back(std::move(ptr));` you're transferring the ownership of the data to a new element and leaving ptr in a *nullptr* state ([read here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator=/)).

After that, if arg is true, since `list.front()` [returns a reference to the first element in the container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/front/), `std::move` takes an r-value out of it and feeds it to the r-value reference obj1. Notice that you're not transferring ownership to another object since you're only asking for a r-value reference to the data. **An r-value reference is, in the end, a reference to a value**.

In the specific case above, regarding the cout statement, it is equivalent to getting just a simple reference to the object

```
Ptr& obj1 = list.front();
```

Now you have both the element into the list and the obj1 r-value reference "pointing" to the same data and modifying one will cause modifying both

```
Ptr&& obj1 = std::move(list.front());
std::cout << obj1.get() << std::endl << list.front().get() << std::endl; // same address
obj1.reset(new int(2));
std::cout << obj1.get() << std::endl << list.front().get() << std::endl; // same other address
```

if you were, as in the false case, to do

```
Ptr obj1 = std::move(list.front());
```

then you would have had the ownership (and thus the nullptr-ify of the list object) transfer to obj1.

If you followed the above reasoning, you can also realize that the line

```
list.pop_front();
```

destroyes the unique_ptr object and leaves the r-value reference into an undefined state. You shouldn't really be returning it (and using it).