# move object into foo(Bar&&) function

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I have a class `Bar` which implements a move constructor.

For an instance `Bar b`, if I call `void fooRvalRef(Bar&&)` using `fooRvalRef(std::move(b))` then the move constructor of Bar is not called.

On the other hand for the function  `void foo(Bar)`, calling it using `foo(std::move(b))` calls the move constructor of Bar.

Why is that?

Comment: [Why is `std::move` named `std::move`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21358432/3953764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move` tries to turn the argument into an rvalue reference, that's all it does, it doesn't move the object. Since it succeeds in your `fooRvalRef` call, there is no need for a move constructor, it simply passes the rvalue reference to the rvalue-reference parameter.

In the case of `foo(Bar)` you're passing by value so, ordinarily, the copy constructor would be called. However in this case you have a move constructor and you are passing an rvalue reference, thanks to `std::move`, so the move constructor is called.