# c++11 move not take effective？

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, move

I tested c++11 move function, but not become effective. Who can tell me why ? Thanks.  The code is as follows：

```
class Base {
  public:
   Base() { cout << "Base" << endl;}
   ~Base() { cout << "~Base" << endl;}

   Base(const Base& base) { cout << "Copy" << endl; }
   Base& operator=(const Base& base) {cout << "operator=" << endl;}

   Base(Base&& base) { cout << "move" << endl;}
   Base& operator=(Base&& base) { cout << "move=" << endl;}
};

Base b;

Base&& GetResult() {
  return std::move(b);
} 

int main() {
Base&& tmp = GetResult();

cout << &b << endl;
cout << &tmp << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
 Base
 0x6013a0
 0x6013a0
 ~Base
```

Why `move copy` and `move operator=` not be called ? And why address is the same ？

Comment: At no point did you construct any more objects other than `b`. You're just referring to `b`.

Comment: `std::move` **does not move anything**.  It just cast an object to a xvalue.

Comment: `std::move` is a cast that changes value categories. It doesn't by itself cause any code execution. All your `GetResult` does is let you access `b` as an xvalue.

Comment: Read the docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: Take out the "&&" from Base&& tmp = GetResult(); and you shall see move getting printed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to the excellent existing answers, I believe the main point of confusion here is what `std::move` does.

**`std::move` does not move.**

It was *abysmally* named.

It only gives you an xvalue referring to whatever you gave it; this xvalue will bind to a rvalue reference where an lvalue won't. This means the result of `std::move` *can* be given to a move constructor or move assignment operator. However, it does not do that for you, and you do not do it here.

---

> Given such strong criticism for the naming, surely you have an alternative suggestion
>   – [user2079303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079303/user2079303)

This is a well-trodden topic, but [the creator of C++ suggests `std::rval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21362110/560648), and [one of the architects of modern C++ suggests `std::rvalue_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove#comment32220979_21358433) (even though you actually get an xvalue).

Personally, I think `std::moveable` would have been a nice middle ground.

Comment: Given such strong criticism for the naming, surely you have an alternative suggestion. I would like to hear it, never mind how it's too late to change now.

Comment: @user2079303: This is a well-trodden topic, but [the creator of C++ suggests `std::rval()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21362110/560648), and [one of the architects of modern C++ suggests `std::rvalue_cast`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove#comment32220979_21358433). Personally (and not only because you get an xvalue actually) I think `std::moveable` would have been a nice middle ground.

Comment: Upvote for *It was abysmally named*. Totally agree! PS: you may want to link [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/3093378) so OP understands what xvalue/prvalue etc are.

Comment: +1 simply for mentioning movable in the comments; though note that the spelling I gave is both preferred and one character shorter. rvalue_cast is reasonable too. Not a fan of rval.

Comment: suggestion: `std::make_moveable`  is similar to all the other `std_make_xxx` see: http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=make

Comment: @RichardCritten: I wrote that originally but it's quite long (hence "middle ground"), plus "make" is being used in a different sense here.

Comment: How about `std::mobilize`? :) movable sounds like it would return true if movable.

Comment: @user2079303: Hah, that's not bad (the stdlib tends to use `is_X` for that kind of thing, but point taken)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Was discussing this at home and my wife came up with `std::free_to_a_good_home`

Comment: @RichardCritten: Hah, sold

Answer (score 3):

> Why move copy and move operator= not be called ?

I assume that by "move copy" you mean "move constructor". Move assignment operator is not called, because you never use the assignment operator.

There are no moves (nor copies) because `Base&&` is a *reference* (an r-value reference to be specific). References refer / point to an object - they do not contain state of the object. When you initialize a reference, no object is copied or moved.

> And why address is the same ？

When the address-of operator is applied to a reference, you get the address of the referred object.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ignore move semantics for a minute, and only think about familiar, C++98 copy constructors. Given the following code, what output would you expect?

```
class Base {
  public:
   Base() { cout << "Base" << endl;}
   ~Base() { cout << "~Base" << endl;}

   Base(const Base& base) { cout << "Copy" << endl; }
   Base& operator=(const Base& base) {cout << "operator=" << endl;}
};

Base b;

Base& GetResult() {
  return b;
} 

int main() {
  Base& tmp = GetResult();

  cout << &b << endl;
  cout << &tmp << endl;
}
```

Of course, you would expect a call to the `Base` default constructor, followed by the address of `b` printed twice, followed by the `Base` destructor. The reason is because you're only constructing one `Base` instance, and never copying it -- you're only using references.

So it is with your example. You're using rvalue references rather than lvalue references, but the point is the same -- *there is only ever one `Base` variable, and no copying or moving ever happens*. If you want to witness move semantics in action, you could try something like this:

```
Base getBase() {
    return Base{};
}

int main() {
    Base tmp = getBase();
    Base other = std::move(tmp);
}
```

(The move out of `getBase()` will probably be optimised out by the compiler, but you should still see the second one.)