# What do they mean by having identity but not movable for Lvalue in C++ 11?

Tags: c++11, value-categories

I am now studying C++ 11 and getting confused by value category of expressions in C++ 11. According to [terminology](http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf) the Lvalue is the top-left point of the W, that is iM (or i-m sometimes) meaning that "has identity but cannot be moved from". This really makes me confused. Please consider the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
    a = std::move(b = c);
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

This example compiled well.

We all know that the assignment `b = c` is an Lvalue then what do they mean by 'cannot be moved from'? Please give examples that can clearly illustrate this!

Thanks!

Comment: [why is std move named so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly speaking:

- an *lvalue* has identity because you can take its address

  ```
  int x;
  &x; // ok
  ```
- an *lvalue* cannot be moved from because it cannot be used as an argument to move constructor/assignment

  ```
  struct Foo 
  {
      Foo(Foo&);  // 0
      Foo(Foo&&); // 1
  };

  Foo x;
  Foo y{x}; // calls 0, not 1
  ```

  in the example above, `x` is an *lvalue*: the copy constructor is invoked. If you want to move from `x`, you need to make it an *rvalue*: this is why you must use `std::move(x)` to **cast it to an rvalue reference**.

  ```
  Foo y{std::move(x)}; // calls 1
  ```

---

In your example `std::move(b = c)` is an *rvalue*, as `std::move` is literally just a `static_cast` to an *rvalue reference*.

Comment: Can you please provide an example that should show compile errors due to "cannot be moved from"?