# Why use std::forward<T> instead of static_cast<T&&>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, rvalue-reference, forwarding

When given code of the following structure

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) { ... }
```

I've often seen library code use `static_cast<Args&&>` within the function for argument forwarding.  Typically, the justification for this is that using a `static_cast` avoids an unnecessary template instantiation.

Given the language's reference collapsing and template deduction rules.  We get perfect forwarding with the `static_cast<Args&&>`, the proof for this claim is below (within error margins, which I am hoping an answer will enlighten)

- When given rvalue references (or for completeness - no reference qualification as in [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ar3wR7AJWUDXrcBR)), this collapses the references in such a way that the result is an rvalue.  The rule used is `&& &&` -> `&&` (rule `1` above)
- When given lvalue references, this collapses the references in such a way that the result is an lvalue.  The rule used here is `& &&` -> `&` (rule `2` above)

This is essentially getting `foo()` to forward the arguments to `bar()` in the example above.  This is the behavior you would get when using `std::forward<Args>` here as well.

---

**Question -** why use `std::forward` in these contexts at all?  Does avoiding the extra instantiation justify breaking convention?

Howard Hinnant's paper [n2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) specified 6 constraints under which any implementation of `std::forward` should behave "correctly".  These were

1. Should forward an lvalue as an lvalue
2. Should forward an rvalue as an rvalue
3. Should not forward an rvalue as an lvalue
4. Should forward less cv-qualified expressions to more cv-qualified expressions
5. Should forward expressions of derived type to an accessible, unambiguous base type
6. Should not forward arbitrary type conversions

(1) and (2) were proven to work correctly with `static_cast<Args&&>` above.  (3) - (6) don't apply here because when functions are called in a deduced context, none of these can occur.

---

Note: I personally prefer to use `std::forward`, but the justification I have is purely that I prefer to stick to convention.

Comment: I would think in some template library, people avoid using `std::forward` because they want the library be self-contained, and don't want to use standard library. They will also implement their own `std::move`, etc.

Comment: @VTT Not in this case, because lvalues are typically deduced as `T&` - https://wandbox.org/permlink/hPucHiFB2pwh53Ox

Comment: `std::forward` and `std::move` are for readability, you *could* use `static_cast` instead to get the same behaviour

Comment: What M.M said. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove/21358433#21358433), Howard mentions `std::move` was introduced to make the proposal more palatable. Then it stuck. I would imagine the same goes for `std::forward`.

Comment: @M.M Your point about readability applies. However, std::move is slightly different in my mind because I don’t see the implementation going out of it’s way to prevent against user errors, making it a simpler 1-1 mapping of a cast. The fact that std::forward typically has two overloads, presumably for safety, makes me think that this situation is potentially more complex. Although, I don’t have a good reason to justify that. Hence, the question I guess.

Comment: @Curious `std::forward` has shenanigans to generate a compile error if you don't explicitly specify the the template parameter (which would lead to undesirable behaviour with no warning)

Comment: @M.M Honestly, `std::forward` could hurt readability in some non-typical use. For example, in the implementation of `std::function::operator()`, clang uses `std::forward` to do `static_cast<T&&>` on arguments that aren't actually deduced, which is quite confusing.

Comment: @liliscent maybe that could be considered bad coding by clang

Comment: Maybe the reverse question would be more interesting: is there any case, where `static_cast<T&&>` is not a `forward`/`move`?

Comment: The compiler union might have work rules that prohibit unnecessary template instantiation, in order to reduce the busy-work that your compilers have to do.

Comment: @liliscent Interesting. I've always considered that to be a correct and clear use for `std::forward`. I don't see `std::forward` as "forward deduced arguments as if calling the underlying function directly with the argument", but as "preserve lvalue/rvalue-ness"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`forward` expresses the intent and it may be safer to use than `static_cast`: `static_cast` considers conversion but some dangerous and supposedly non-intentional conversions are detected with `forward`:

```
struct A{
   A(int);
   };

template<class Arg1,class Arg2>
Arg1&& f(Arg1&& a1,Arg2&& a2){
   return static_cast<Arg1&&>(a2); //  typing error: a1=>a2
   }

template<class Arg1,class Arg2>
Arg1&& g(Arg1&& a1,Arg2&& a2){
   return forward<Arg1>(a2); //  typing error: a1=>a2
   }

void test(const A a,int i){
   const A& x = f(a,i);//dangling reference
   const A& y = g(a,i);//compilation error
  }
```

<sub>Example of error message: [compiler explorer link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ykHvYk)</sub>

---

How applies this justification: *Typically, the justification for this is that using a static_cast avoids an unnecessary template instantiation.*

Is the compilation time more problematic than code maintainability? Should the coder even lose its time considering minimizing "unnecessary template instantiation" at every line in the code?

When a template is instantiated, its instantiation causes instantiations of template that are used in its definition and declaration. So that, for example if you have a function as:

```
  template<class T> void foo(T i){
     foo_1(i),foo_2(i),foo_3(i);
     }
```

where `foo_1`,`foo_2`,`foo_3` are templates, the instantiation of `foo` will cause 3 instantiations. Then recursively if those functions cause the instantiation of other 3 template functions, you could get 3*3=9 instantiations for example. So you can consider this chain of instantiation as a tree where a root function instantiation can cause thousands of instantiations as an exponentially growing ripple effect. On the other hand a function like `forward` is a leaf in this instantiation tree. So avoiding its instantiation may only avoid 1 instantiation.

So, the best way to avoid template instantiation explosion is to use dynamic polymorphism for "root" classes and type of argument of "root" functions and then use static polymorphism only for time critical functions that are virtually upper in this instantiation tree.

So, in my opinion using `static_cast` in place `forward` to avoid instantiations is a lost of time compared to the benefit of using a more expressive (and safer) code. Template instantiation explosion is more efficiently managed at code architecture level.

Comment: It's not the *conversion* that is being checked, the check is merely against rvalue -> lvalue forwarding. The code above will compile if `g(a, i)` is changed to `g(std::move(a), i)`.

Comment: How is this brace-style called?

Comment: @YSC: seems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Ratliff_style

Comment: @liliscent Not necessarily, you can make this work, like you said, but the conversion is prevented in this case.  And I see that as a consequence of `std::forward`'s implementation.  It doesn't prevent all possible footguns, but at least a few of them. This is the only difference between `static_cast` and `std::forward`.  So it makes sense as a motivating reason to use `std::forward` over `static_cast` to me.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the example about the difference between `forward` and `static_cast`: In this example, the user is trying to forward the second argument as if it was the first.

Answer (score 17):

Scott Meyers says that `std::forward` and `std::move` are mainly for convenience. He even states that `std::forward` can be used to perform the functionality of both `std::forward` and `std::move`.
Some excerpts from "Effective Modern C++":

> **Item 23:Understand std::move and std::forward**
>   ...
>   The story for `std::forward` is similar to that for `std::move`, but whereas `std::move` unconditionally casts its argument to an `rvalue`, `std::forward` does it only under certain conditions. `std::forward` is a conditional cast. It casts to an `rvalue` only if its argument was initialized with an `rvalue`.
>   ...
>   Given that both `std::move` and `std::forward` boil down to casts, the only difference being that `std::move` always casts, while `std::forward` only sometimes does, *you might ask whether we can dispense with `std::move` and just use `std::forward` everywhere*. From a purely technical perspective, the answer is yes: `std::forward` can do it all. `std::move` isn’t necessary. **Of course, neither function is really necessary, because we could write casts everywhere, but I hope we agree that that would be, well, yucky.**
>   ...
>   `std::move`’s attractions are convenience, reduced likelihood of error, and greater clarity...

For those interested, comparison of `std::forward<T>` vs `static_cast<T&&>`  in [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/cMILC3) (without any optimization) when called with `lvalue` and `rvalue`.

Comment: If I want to change an lvalue to an rvalue, I have to use `std::move`, but not `std::forward`. Right?

Comment: Yes. move casts its argument to an rvalue.

Comment: So it is not correct to say `std::forward` can do it all and `std::move` isn’t necessary. :-)

Comment: Sort of expected this comment from you. :-) I don't think that scott meyers meant that we can just replace move with forward. He gives an example in that item implementing move in terms of forward. " std::move requires only a function argument (rhs.s), while std::forward requires both a function argument (rhs.s) and a template type argument (std::string). Then note that the type we pass to std::forward should be a non-reference, because that’s the convention for encoding that the argument being passed is an rvalue (see Item 28). contd...

Comment: ...Together, this means that std::move requires less typing than std::forward, and it spares us the trouble of passing a type argument that encodes that the argument we’re passing is an rvalue. It also eliminates the possibility of our passing an incorrect type (e.g., std::string&, which would result in the data member s being copy constructed instead of move constructed).  More importantly, the use of std::move conveys an unconditional cast to an rvalue, while the use of std::forward indicates a cast to an rvalue only for references to which rvalues have been bound.

Comment: I think some context is lost in your quotation of Item 23. I re-read Item 23 and remember his point now. `std::move` is more convenient for the cast, but it is still possible to use something like `std::forward<T>(obj)` to achieve a similar purpose, if one is careful with `T`.

Comment: @P.W your last sentence of your last comment is incorrect because some rvalues may be bound to const lvalue references

Comment: @M.M: Yes, looks like Scott Meyers did not take that into account. I was quoting him verbtim . :)

Answer (score 5):

Here are my 2.5, not so technical cents for this: the fact that today `std::forward` is indeed just a plain old `static_cast<T&&>` does not mean that tomorrow it also will be implemented in exactly the same way. I think the committee needed something to reflect the desired behaviour of what `std::forward` achieves today hence, the `forward` which does not forward anything anywhere came into existence.

With having the required behaviour and expectations formalized under the umbrella of `std::forward`, just theoretically speaking, noone impedes a future implementer to provide the `std::forward` as not the `static_cast<T&&>` but something specific his own implementation, without actually taking into consideration `static_cast<T&&>` because the only fact that matters is the correct usage and behaviour of `std::forward`.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that `forward` will ever do something else. Think of how much code that will break...

Comment: @Rakete1111 That is why my answer is just hypothetical, highly debatable and pure virtual :)