# Why does the Microsoft implementation of concept std::output_iterator<It,T> contain a cast of type T?

Tags: c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

Ranges are complete in VS2019, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-ranges-are-complete-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-10/

Why does the output_iterator concept have a static cast in the definition below taken from the Microsoft implementation?

```
// CONCEPT output_iterator
template <class _It, class _Ty>
concept output_iterator = input_or_output_iterator<_It> && indirectly_writable<_It, _Ty>
    && requires(_It __i, _Ty&& __t) {
        *__i++ = static_cast<_Ty&&>(__t);
    };
```

The definition on cppreference contains no such cast.
[image]

Comment: `static_cast<T&&>` here is equivalent to `std::forward<T>`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257824/why-use-stdforwardt-instead-of-static-castt) might help

Comment: That clears things up, thanks. It seems though that this concept constraint may lead to unwanted type conversions. If `It` is an iterator with value type double then `std::output_iterator<It, double>`, `std::output_iterator<It, float>` and `std::output_iterator<It, int>` are all true.