# Did not get a compile time error after deleting copy/move constructors and assignment operators during passing object to function

Tags: c++, c++11

I  the following code I have explictly forbidden copying and moving `Dummy` object using `delete` specifier for copy and move constructors and for copy and move assignment operators:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Dummy
{
    explicit Dummy(const std::string& value) : value_(value) {}
    Dummy(const Dummy&) = delete;
    Dummy& operator=(const Dummy&) = delete;
    Dummy(Dummy&&) = delete;
    Dummy& operator=(Dummy&&) = delete;

    void print_this_address() const
    {
        std::cout << "this address: " << this << "\n";
    }

    std::string value_;
};

void foo(Dummy&& obj)
{
    std::cout << obj.value_ << "\n";
    obj.print_this_address();
}

int main()
{
    Dummy obj("42");
    obj.print_this_address();
    foo(std::move(obj));
    std::cout << obj.value_ << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs well and I'm getting the following output in my terminal:

```
this address: 0x7ffeeb6d2a20
42
this address: 0x7ffeeb6d2a20
42
```

Can someone explains for me what's happening in this code and why I didn't get compile error and have the same object in `foo` function as in `main`. function?

Comment: Relevet/possible followup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never actually try to copy or move the object, which is why you don't get an error.

The parameter `Dummy &&obj` is an rvalue reference parameter, meaning it can bind to rvalues but not to lvalues. It's still a reference, just like `const Dummy &obj` would be (which would also work in your case).

What `std::move` does is not to move anything, it casts its parameter to an rvalue reference. This makes it possible to pass it to functions expecting an rvalue (for example, a move constructor). For more details have a look at [the answer linked by StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove).

Answer (score 3):

It's not because you called `std::move` that your object has moved. It was just "prepared" to be moved.

As such, you prepared `obj` but never tried to move it somewhere else, hence the no compiler error, and as you never actually moved it (you just passed an rvalue reference to your object into `foo`), you get the same result, because `obj` never changed.

Comment: Is it passed by reference as a result?

Comment: The parameter `Dummy &&obj` is an rvalue reference, a reference that can bind to rvalues but not to lvalues. So the object _is_ passed by reference.