# Understanding Move Semantics of C++ Standard

Tags: c++, visual-c++, move-semantics

I'm trying to get my head around move semantics. I become confused because I couldn't find out why we need this and how should we use it ideally.

For example, when we move an object with by std::move, it makes the object nullptr. why does this happen? Also, why std::move turn an object to rvalue? how does this happen? Why after using std::move with a variable, it doesn't fill it with null, but when I use it with an object like vector, after moving it, it fills it with nullptr.

I hope, someone explaining the move semantics and other semantics of CPP step by step. The more I read about it, the more confused I become. It is one of the most complicated subjects of CPP programming.

Comment: `when we move an object with by std::move, it makes the object nullptr.` What? `Also, why std::move turn an object to rvalue?` Because thats its purpose `how does this happen?` a simple cast.

Comment: Which book are you using? It's not complicated at all (compared to many other aspects of C++)

Comment: `std::move` is nothing but a *cast*. In and of itself it doesn't change any objects. All it does is *enable* a move in some situations.

Comment: I hesitate to even call it a cast, tbh. No types change; it's just the identity function. But because it's a function its result is an rvalue expression. Yowzer.

Comment: You know what, I take it back: the hackiness of all of this does make it somewhat complicated to fully grok I suppose

Comment: Recommended further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove/21358433#21358433

Comment: @HowardHinnant I've now linked to that from my A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When we move an object with by std::move

No. `std::move` doesn't move things. [It gives us an *rvalue expression* referring to some object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358433/560648) An rvalue expression results in overload resolution picking functions that take *rvalue references*, which is convenient because now we will pick those instead of the functions that take values, or *lvalue references*, which traditionally do copy-like things. Such functions tend to be constructors (so-called "move constructors") or assignment operators (so-called "move assignment operators") because it is during construction and assignment that moving is useful.

> it makes the object nullptr

That depends entirely on what said function does. Typically, an object that's worth moving has indirect state, like a pointer to some dynamically-allocated resource. And if said object *is* moveable, its move constructor is best off doing a swap on those pointers. If it didn't leave the source object's pointer as `nullptr` then you have *two* objects owning the resource. That wasn't a move; it was a [shallow] copy.

A full discussion of the hows and the whys is out of scope of a Q&A, but [any good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have one.

Also, if this all sounds like a hack, that's because it is one. C++ is a hodge-podge of hacks built on hacks to provide additional functionality over time. In this case, we needed (read: *wanted*) a way to create a different kind of constructor (and assignment operator), a kind that would take a non-`const` reference and could modify the source object (to "steal" its resources), and to achieve that we had to introduce a new kind of reference that would only bind to *rvalues* (because we were already using everything else for copies), and then we had to introduce a utility function that would turn the name of an object into an *rvalue* … hence, `std::move` was born, the utility function that doesn't move anything.