# Move semantics with std::vector misunderstanding when passing to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

I try to understand the concept of move semantic and did some tests. I have the following function:

```
// testing the move semantic when passing 
// argument to be modified without copying

void process_copy( std::vector<int>&& aVec)
{
    std::cout << "Move semantic\n";
    aVec.push_back(42);
}
```

now in the main function, the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> w_vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    process_copy( std::move(w_vec));
}
```

I expect that the `w_vec` is now empty since I pass it with move cast (cast lvalue to rvalue). But the result is `w_vec` contains *6* elements now (*42* has been added to the vector).

Something that I miss? Is `std::vector` is a moveable object?

Comment: `std::move()` just casts. You have to pass the result to something that will move-from, if you want to get moved-from, not just cast... lemme find one of the many duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is std::move(), and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Comment: "_argument to be modified without copying_" - so just pass a normal reference `& vec`, not an rvalue reference `&& vec`. Then you won't have to use `std::move()` to cast to an rvalue reference. Move semantics don't seem to mean what you think they mean, and `std::move()` alone will never move, just cast to an rvalue ref so the receiver _might_ move from same.

Comment: Just like your title said, it's semantics.   No code to perform a move was called, so no move happened.

Answer (score 14):

An image of my *[CoreCpp 2019](https://2019.corecpp.org)* t-shirt might be relevant here.

[image: CoreCpp 2019 t-shirt]

This is the front.

[image: t-shirt front]

It's interesting to note that this behavior of `std::move` was a bit surprising [even for Howard Hinnant himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358432/why-is-stdmove-named-stdmove), the man behind rvalue and move semantics. However he got a very thorough answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358433/2085626).

Comment: I think it is safe to say that I was never surprised by the behavior I designed.  Self-answer is an [approved technique for disseminating knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @HowardHinnant It was a joke. I'm also using occasionally the technique of answering my own questions. Hope it was not an offending joke, if it is I can of course edit to rephrase or remove it. Anyway, your question and answer is a great resource on the subject, if the explanation on the t-shirt I've posted is not enough.

Comment: No, I'm not offended at all.  And thanks for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21358432/576911)!

Answer (score 4):

What you may be missing is that you are just binding an *rvalue reference* to the vector you pass; you are moving no vector object at all.

The `process_copy()` parameter is of type `std::vector<int>&&`, i.e., an rvalue reference to `std::vetor<int>`:

```
void process_copy(std::vector<int>&& aVec)
```

By using `std::move()` when calling `process_copy()` as in:

```
process_copy(std::move(w_vec));
```

You are just making it possible to bind this reference – i.e., `process_copy()`'s parameter, `aVec` – to the argument – i.e., the vector `w_vec`. That is, the following does not compile:

```
process_copy(w_vec);
```

Because you can't bind an rvalue reference (`aVec`) to an *lvalue* (`w_vec`).

---

If you want the vector argument `w_vec` to be moved when calling `process_copy()`, then you could have the function to take an `std::vector<int>` *by value* instead and move construct this parameter at the moment of calling the function:

```
void process_copy(std::vector<int> aVec) // <-- not a reference
{
    aVec.push_back(42);
}
```

By marking the vector argument with `std::move()` when calling this `process_copy()`, the parameter `aVec` will be move constructed – so the vector argument will end up in a moved-from state.