# How can I declare a constant data member but not initialize it until later?

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

Lets say in my main method, I declare a const int array pointer pointing to an array created on the heap. I then want to initialize it's values (using the memory address) in a constructor TryInitialize() and then print them out. This is not working and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "part_one.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string createTable(unsigned int* acc, double* bal, int n) {
    string s;
    char buf[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sprintf_s(buf,"%7u\t%10.2f\n",acc[i], bal[i]);
            s += string(buf);
    }

    return s;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    const int *tempInt = new const int[4];
    TryInitialize(tempInt);
    std::cout << tempInt[1] << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my code for my constructor:

```
#include "part_one.h"


TryInitialize::TryInitialize(void) {

}

TryInitialize::TryInitialize(int constInt[]) {
    constInt[0] = 8;
    constInt[1] = 0;
    constInt[2] = 0;
    constInt[3] = 8;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not initialize it until later"? Do you plan on having a user input it? How do you plan to initialize it? If you plan on having the user input it via `std::cin` then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279601/are-there-any-tricks-to-use-stdcin-to-initialize-a-const-variable

Comment: You shouldn't. That is the point of `const`.

Comment: Where is your class?  Having a constructor modify its *parameters* is a terrible idea (so terrible that the only standard library class to do so got replaced).  It's supposed to initialize members of the new object, not have unrelated side-effects.

Comment: I know, but that is my goal I'm trying to see if that is even possible. Pseudo idea: 
Main method-
const int x;
NewClass(x)
  constructor-
   initialize x;
sys print x val;

Comment: @TaylorWhite, while there are useful C++ idioms where an object changes its parameter (for instance, aquire a lock and free it automatically in the destructor), the parameter isn't `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not change a `const` value.

For what you trying to accomplish I'd recommend declaring a non-const pointer and a const pointer and assigning the non-const one to the const one after the initialization:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int *tempTempInt = new int[4];
    TryInitialize(tempInt);
    const int* const tempInt = tempTempInt;
    std::cout << tempInt[1] << endl; //this is now constant.

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Also pay attention where you put the const in the pointer declaration:

```
const int* const tempInt = tempTempInt;
```

In the declaration above the second `const` means that you cannot change the pointer; the first `const` means that you cannot change the pointed value(s).

Comment: Rephrase your last sentence, right now it's unclear and probably wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to not do it that way? I understand the purpose of constant, but I'm trying to see if I can get around it. For instance lets say I pass by reference the memory address, then set the values in another class. Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, it had a typo as well

Comment: @user2031046 This is C++. Everything has a workaround. (That is why I began the answer with should not and not cannot.) But why use hacks when you can write good code instead?

Comment: I'm just trying to see what I can get away with :)

Comment: @TaylorWhite Getting around it is not a good idea as it may fool the optimizer and you get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the pointer as `const int*`. The `const` modifier means that you cannot change the array values.

Either remove the `const`, or create an initializer method for it that can allocate the array and return it (unlike a constructor).

```
const int* init_my_array()
{
  int * ret = new int[4];
  ret [0] = 8;
  ret [1] = 0;
  ret [2] = 0;
  ret [3] = 8;
  return ret;
}
...
const int *tempInt = init_my_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Why? Because if it's const, then it can't be changed once the object has been constructed. Note: **Even setting it** is effectively **changing** its value from its uninitialized value, which goes against the definition of const to begin with.

Comment: This. Succinct, and to the point. `How do I change const?` You don't.