# Why can't I read a value from the user and make it a constant?

Tags: c++, constants, iostream

After inputting the following code, I would get an error.

```
const int quantity;
cout << "How much spacing do you want in-between the frames? " ;
cin >> quantity;
```

> error: uninitialised const 'quantity'[-fpermissive]
>
> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>'

This does not happen if I just use the type **int**

```
int quantity;
cout << "How much spacing do you want in-between the frames? " ;
cin >> quantity;
```

Which compiles without a problem. I'm new to C++ so I'd just like to know why this is.

Comment: `const` means constant. You can't assign a value to the constant except during its initialization. It's the `variable` that could be assigned a value anytime during the program life.

Comment: This thread says why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279601/are-there-any-tricks-to-use-stdcin-to-initialize-a-const-variable

Comment: So there is no way to assign a value to a constant through user input?

Comment: No It's not possible.

Comment: You cannot (directly at least), but you could expose a `const` reference or a copy using a `get` function to whatever code you might be worried about modifying `quantity`.

Comment: read an int : `int dummy; cin >> dummy;` then initialize your constant with it `const int myConstant = dummy`.

Comment: Or you could say `int input; cin >> input; const int quantity = input;`. The word `const` doesn’t mean you need to know at compile time, just that you need to know when you create the variable.

Comment: @batMan there are two of us who left answers showing exactly how it's possible.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's tricky. It's not possible directly using Istream. That's what I mean.

Comment: @batMan then say it explicitly.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate, but I don't think that the linked question (what in general does `const` mean?) applies here. I think this is a specific misunderstanding about `const` and how it interacts with streams, with the nuance being "`const` means the value can never change after initialization" versus "`const` means that the value can never change after it's first assigned."

Comment: @templatetypedef: I was the closer (as you probably knew). I think the answers in the other thread are the same as for this one; you cannot modify a variable marked as `const` (without a `const_cast`). You're right, though, what OP wants here is to simultaneously declare and initialize a `const` variable from a stream, which is not possible. I'm cool with keeping it open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define the variable as

```
const int quantity;
```

you're saying "I'd like an `int` called `quantity`, and under no circumstances do I want its value to ever change." As a result, if you then write

```
cin >> quantity;
```

the compiler says something to the effect of "wait - you want me to change the value of `quantity` by replacing it with whatever the user entered, but earlier you said that you never wanted me to change it!"

My sense is that you wanted to make it so that after you give an initial value to `quantity` that value never changes, but with `const` variables that initial value needs to be set when the variable is created. You could therefore try something like this:

```
const int quantity = readValue();
```

for some function `readValue()` that reads and returns an `int` value. That way, the compiler sees that `quantity` is given a fixed value, it knows that the value never changes, and you never try to directly `cin` into the value of `quantity`.

For a more technical perspective on the errors you got: when the compiler read

```
const int quantity;
```

without any value assigned to it, it reported an error because it's unusual to create a constant without giving it a value. (I can see from your code that you *meant* to give it a value, but the way you did it wasn't legal and the compiler didn't piece the two things together). The second error about `operator >>` resulted because none of the different ways that you can read something from `cin` (read a string, read an `int`, read a `char`, etc.) applied, since each of them assumed that they can get a mutable (modifiable) view of the value in question. Again, both of these issues stem from the fact that the compiler saw your code as two separate independent errors rather than one large "oops, that's not how `const` works" error.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize a `const` local variable only once, at the moment it's declared. Your example looks like it couldn't possibly work, but it's simple if you add a level of indirection.

```
int ReadAnInt()
{
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}

const int quantity = ReadAnInt();
```

Comment: This problem of constant input is, I think, one of the bigger problems with the iostreams design.

Comment: @DanielH There are easy workarounds though: `const int a = *std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin);` Horrible, yes. Impossible without defining another function, no.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I didn’t say it was impossible, but if that’s the best workaround available it is still a problem with the API.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` qualifier means that the variable is immutable and you cannot change its value. The first error is telling you that the variable is uninitialize.

`cin` allows you to assign a value to a variable, which immediately contradicts your `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise `quantity` the moment you declare it. Furthermore, you can't assign a value to it later on; after all, it is constant.

Answer (score 0):

First you put the same code in both of the boxes. 
I admit you put the `const` symbol in the first source. 
Second a `const` must be initialized at declaration in C++. 
Thus you should put the code as following

```
 int value;
 cin >> value;
 const int my_num = value;
```