# Extract from an ifstream without a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, ifstream, syntactic-sugar

`ifstream` offers an overload of `operator>>` to extract values from the next line of the stream. However, I tend to find myself doing this often:

```
int index;
input >> index;
arr[index] = <something>;
```

Is there any way to get this data into the `[index]` without having to create this temporary variable?

Comment: Deepens on `arr` and `<something>`. But ultimately, I'm leaning towards no simple solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller arr is a simple `vector<T>`, something is unrelated to `arr` and `index`

Comment: Even if you get the data into the `[index]` without creating an explicit local (temporary) variable, you will still be getting an unnamed temporary variable.  The compiler is able to optimize the explicit local variable quite well.  I'd rather be explicit than tricky, but that's just me.

Comment: @Justin yeah that's probably a very sensible option

Comment: @Eljay that's true, I'm new to c++ so I assumed there might be something idiomatic to do there

Comment: Speaking of idiomatic C++. Depending on `T`, prebuilding the entire vector with "dummy values" and then assigning could be unidiomatic in and of itself.

Comment: @Eljay A one-liner function will be optimized as well as long as its implementation is visible. The issue is what OP considers more readable.

Comment: @StoryTeller can you go on a bit? as I said still a bit new to c++ :)

Comment: @It'sNotALie. - You initialize a `T` at the index after constructing it. Goes against the grain of having c'tors. It's like having a public `init()` method, a distinct anti-pattern. But that ultimately depends on `T`. I think there may be a bit of an XY element to this question.

Comment: Since input can generally fail it is necessary to verify the read attempt was successful. The interface is deliberately the way it is to make testing idiomatic: `if (in >> value) { /* use value */ }`. Also, order of evaluation is undefined and something like `array[read<int>(in)] = read<T>(in);` is bound to do the wrong thing (your `<something>`  should better be nit a read of the same stream).

Comment: It would be better to check `index` is what you think it is before using it imo

Comment: @DietmarKühl In C++17, `array[read<int>(in)] = read<T>(in);` is guaranteed to evaluate the rhs first, so you'd have `read<T>(in)`, then `read<int>(in)`, then `array[...]`, then `... = ...`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/1896169

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any tricks to use std::cin to initialize a const variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279601/are-there-any-tricks-to-use-stdcin-to-initialize-a-const-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to extract the next value from an `istream`:

```
template <typename T> // T must be DefaultConstructible
T read(std::istream& input) {
    T result;
    input >> result;
    return result;
}
```

Then, you could just write:

```
arr[read<int>(input)] = <something>;
```

Although you should probably write

```
arr.at(read<int>(input)) = <something>;
```

Because otherwise you open yourself up to a buffer-overflow vulnerability. If the input file had an integer out of range, you'd be writing out of bounds.

Comment: Sorry, what does DefaultConstructible mean?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Basically, this function lets you write `read<MyType>(input)`. This function requires that `MyType` has a default constructor (a constructor with no arguments), otherwise the line `T result;` will fail

Comment: ah I see, this probably seems like the best solution then :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do this by just constructing a temporary [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) for example:

```
arr[*istream_iterator<int>(input)] = something
```

Comment: I've just discovered what I'd consider a duplicate of this question which didn't have this answer so [I've added this answer there as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49580321/2642059) and voted to dupe this question. I've beefed up my answer over there if anyone would care to go check it out.