# C++11 Lambda Generator - How to signal last element or end?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I am looking at the lambda generators from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735970 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639820. 
I would like to adapt these to a template version and I'm wondering what I should return to signal that the generator has reached its end.

Consider

```
template<typename T>
std::function<T()> my_template_vector_generator(std::vector<T> &v) {
    int idx = 0;
    return [=,&v]() mutable {
        return v[idx++];
    };
}
```

The `[=,&v]` addition is mine and I hope it's correct. For now, it lets me change the vector outside as expected. Please comment on this if you have a bad feeling about it...
For reference, this works (REQUIRE is from [catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch)):

```
std::vector<double> v({1.0, 2.0, 3.0});
auto vec_gen = my_template_vector_generator(v);
REQUIRE( vec_gen() == 1 );
REQUIRE( vec_gen() == 2 );
v[2] = 5.0;
REQUIRE( vec_gen() == 5.0 );
```

That vector version obviously requires knowledge of `v.size()` at the call site. I'd like to go without that by returning something that indicates the generator is empty.

Brainstorming, I can think of the following:

- return `pair<T, bool>` and indicate `false` once there are no more values.
- return iterators to the container values and iterate `for (auto it=gen(); it!=gen.end(); it=gen()) {cout << *it << endl;}`
- wrapping the generator in a class and implementing an `empty()` method. Not entirely sure how that would work, however.

Does either of these versions feel good to you? Do you have another idea?
I'd particularly be interested in implications when mapping such a generator or combining them recursively (see this [C++14 blog post for inspiration](http://cpptruths.blogspot.sg/2015/06/fun-with-lambdas-c14-style-part-4.html)).

**Update**:
After hearing the optional suggestions, I implemented something based on unique_ptr.

```
template<typename T>
std::function<std::unique_ptr<T>()> my_pointer_template_vector_generator(std::vector<T> &v) {
    int idx = 0;
    return [=,&v]() mutable {
        if (idx < v.size()) {
            return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(v[idx++]));
        } else {
            return std::unique_ptr<T>();
        }
    };
}
```

This seems to work, consider the following passing test.

```
TEST_CASE("Pointer generator terminates as expected") {
    std::vector<double> v({1.0, 2.0, 3.0});

    int k = 0;
    auto gen = my_pointer_template_vector_generator(v);

    while(auto val = gen()) {
        REQUIRE( *val == v[k++] );
    }

    REQUIRE( v.size() == k );
}
```

I have some concerns about creating lots of new T. I suppose I could also return pointers into the vector and nullptr otherwise. That should work in the same way. What do you think about this?

Comment: Use boost::optional.

Comment: that looks great indeed, but depending on boost is not an option for the small project this is for.

Comment: You can try std::experimental::optional if your compiler supports it.

Comment: That looks very interesting. I investigated a bit and it seems that this is only available with std=c++14 under g++. Hmm. How hard would it be to conceive such a wrapper on the spot in C++11? nullptr and unique_ptr together may reproduce something like this, no?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as it looks like just study example i could suggest to add exception as end of collection. But do not use it in real code.