# The lambda return type in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

> Lambda with function bodies that contain anything other than a single
>   return statement that do not specify a return type return void.
>
> via 《C++ Primer》 5th Edition, Page 389.
>
> However, if we write the seemingly equivalent program using an if
>   statement, our code won't compile:
>
> ```
> //error: can't deduce the return type for the lambda.
>
> transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vi.begin(), [](int i) { if(i < 0) return -i; else return i; } );
> ```
>
> via 《C++ Primer》 5th Edition, Page 396.

I write a program in Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<int> vi{ 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6 };
    /* Is the return type void？ */
    transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vi.begin(), [](int i) {
                                                    if (i < 0) return -i;
                                                    else return i; });

    for (int i : vi)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But it can correctly run.

And then, I add some statements in Visual Studio:

```
auto f = [](int i) {
                    if (i < 0) return -i;
                    else return i; };
```

As I move the cursor to the f, it shows me that the f's return type is int.

Why is this?

I am confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ Primer 5th Edition covers C++11, and in C++11, the statement you quoted is true. However, [C++14 supports deducing return types in more situations](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generalized-return), including when a lambda has multiple return statements, as long as they all return the same type. Presumably your version of Visual Studio supports C++14, or at least this feature of it.

Comment: I think *as long as they all return the same value* should be *as long as they all return the same type*

Comment: The committee decided that the behavior as described in the published C++11 standard (and C++ Primer) is a defect. More recent versions of the compilers should accept this even in their C++11 mode.

Comment: @T.C. interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for explaining that. But where can I find the information about "The committee decided that the behavior as described in the published C++11 standard (and C++ Primer) is a defect"?

Comment: I may find the information about that [US 30](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#US30). And [Is there a reason on not allowing lambdas to deduce the return type if it contains more than one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285659/6099429)